# ORA-24247 when sending through FTP

Tags: oracle, ftp, ora-24247

I've been trying to solve this problem for days and I always get the same error over and over. I am user Oracle SQL Developer Version 3.2.20.09 and  I want to send files through FTP with this code

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE subirFTP(dirServer VARCHAR2, port VARCHAR2, usr VARCHAR2, pass VARCHAR2, dirRemitente VARCHAR2, dirDestinatario VARCHAR2, nombreArchivo VARCHAR2)
IS
  l_conn  UTL_TCP.connection;
BEGIN
  l_conn := ftp.login(dirServer,port,usr,pass);
  ftp.binary(p_conn => l_conn);
  ftp.put(p_conn => l_conn,
          p_from_dir => dirRemitente,
          p_from_file => nombreArchivo,
          p_to_file => dirDestinatario);
  ftp.logout(l_conn);
END subirFTP;

Informe de error:
ORA-24247: acceso de red denegado por la lista de control de acceso (ACL)
ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_TCP", línea 17
ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_TCP", línea 267
ORA-06512: en "WORKFLOW.FTP", línea 76
ORA-06512: en "WORKFLOW.SUBIRFTP", línea 5
ORA-06512: en línea 2
```

Answer (score 1):

this error would be thown on 11g due to the ACL (access control list) restictions. you need to grant the privs to your "WORKFLOW" user to communicate with the FTP server.

you can see the existing grants in

```
select * from dba_network_acls
```

your dba can grant access with something like:

```
begin
  dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl(acl => 'ftp.xml',
                                    description => 'Enables FTP',
                                    principal => 'WORKFLOW', 
                                    is_grant => true,
                                    privilege => 'connect');
end;
/
begin
  dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl(acl => 'ftp.xml',
                                    host => 'yourhost.com',
                                    lower_port => ftp port);
end;
/
commit;
```

see [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_networkacl_adm.htm) for more info.

Comment: Well, I've tried using the select * from dba_network_acls and it shows me this error code Error SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. Is that table something that only the dba can see?

Comment: @AllanMiranda - not necessarily only DBAs, but anybody with sufficient privileges (e.g. `select any dictionary`); but you'll also need someone with execute privs on the `dbms_network_acl_admin` package to set those up. So you'll probably have to get your DBA involved at some point, either to do this for you or to grant you the privs you need to set this up yourself.