# Oracle 12c ORA-24247 network access denied by access control list (ACL) when using FTP

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, acl, ora-24247

I am working with *Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production* and trying to use the an ftp package (UTL_TCP). Here the procedure:

```
declare 
    l_conn UTL_TCP.connection;
    l_list ftp.t_string_table   := ftp.t_string_table(); 
begin
    l_conn := ftp.login('ftp.myhost.com', 21, 'user', 'password');
    ftp.nlst(p_conn => l_conn,p_dir  => 'outbox',p_list => l_list);
    ftp.logout(l_conn);
end;
```

The error is raised for **ftp.nlst**.

I configured the ACLs in this way:`select * from dba_network_acls;` returns

```
HOST           | LOWER_PORT | UPPER_PORT | ACL                   | ACLID            | ACL_OWNER
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ftp.myhost.com |  null      | null       | /myaclspath/myacl.xml | 00000000800027C5 | SYS
*              |  null      | null       | NETWORK_ACL_5A1900... | 0000000080002724 | SYS
```

and `select * from dba_network_acl_privileges` returns

```
ACL                   | ACLID            | PRINCIPAL | PRIVILEGE | IS_GRANT | INVERT | START_DATE | END_DATE | ACL_OWNER
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/myaclspath/myacl.xml | 00000000800027C5 | MYDBUSER  | resolve   | true     | false  |            |          |SYS
/myaclspath/myacl.xml | 00000000800027C5 | MYDBUSER  | connect   | true     | false  |            |          |SYS
```

I read about a similar error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816179/ora-24247-when-sending-through-ftp) and check the setup of the ACL as [here](http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2010/03/17/oracle-11g-access-control-list-and-ora-24247/) but I can't figure it out why the network access is denied after login.

Thanks in advance fr any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question for the benefit of others.

Reviewing the steps found [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/fine-grained-access-to-network-services-11gr1) I inspect the ftp package and realized that each "command" send a PASV before execution. In this case the PASV change the connection established with login.

The login success because of the ACL for **ftp.myhost.com** but every following ftp command fail because it is not sent as **ftp.myhost.com** but as **111.222.333.444** that is the relative IP. Adding an ACL for the IP resolve the ORA-24247 error.

My solution is clearly mentioned [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/ftp-from-plsql#acl) and it is my fault to not double check the right documentation but I would like to share here the issue.